# jQuery difference between function and self invoking anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What is the differences between a normal function and a self invoking anonymous function? And in which cases should i use a self invoking anonymous function? I really dont get the difference between them. And how does i use a SIAF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function in Javascript is a first class citizen and can be passed around like an object. When you define a function like so:

```
function() { ... };
```

That is all you are doing. Defining it. It is not being used at this point. You can assign it to a variable and call it later on if you wish or pass the variable to another function as an argument.

A self invoking anonymous function is an extremely useful pattern component used for namespacing in Javascript. I prefer to use the more accurate name for it of immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). To understand this pattern I recommend you read up on closures in javascript: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```
(function(namespace, $, undefined){ //undefined is specified here as it can be overwritten in javascript. This ensures we have a true undefined value within our namespace. Make sure not to pass in any argument for this.
    var text = "hello world"; // private member
    var namespace.text = "hellow world"; //public member
}(window.namespace  = window.namespace || {}, jQuery)); //This section calls this function immediately and creates a closure. We pass in the window.namespace argument to give us access to all public member of the namespace.
```

This provides you with a namespace to avoid global scope pollution and allow you to define private functions and members.

You can find more information here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Did i understand it right, that vars in a SIAF arent global vars? So that i cant use them with window-function?

Comment: They aren't strictly global variables. But if you make them public within your SIAF(or IIFE) you can access them elsewhere in your javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

well I am sure the are MANY uses for SIAF! but mainly it is used for **namespacing** and **privacy**!

**for privacy**

```
var normalkey=89000333;
var privateKey= (function(param){                     
    var secretkey = 123411; 
   //it is private , nothing outside this function will know of it
    var newkey=param+secretkey ;                                     
    return newkey
  })(normalkey); //passing normalkey as param
```

you got a privateKey without calling a function to calculate it yourself and the secretkey used to calculate the privateKey is safe inside SIAF.

**for namespacing**

```
  var fruits= (function() {
    return {
       name: ["apple", "orange"];
       color: [{"red","green"},"orange"]
    }
   })();
```

instead of declaring fruitname,fruitcolor.. so on.. in the global namespace, you can get everything from 'fruits'

**for the purpose of self-invoking**

```
$(function(){}); //seem familiar? -jquery
```